# sending mail with attachement (or without) using mailx on centos linux

Tags: centos, email

in solaris I used to send mail easily by doing:

uuencode file.txt file txt | mailx abc@xzy.com.

I can't find "uuencode" in centos and mailx always stop for CC.
I want to automatically send the email with no questions at all

Answer (score 0):

You have to install sharutils package (yum install sharutils) to get uuencode